# Iron Router (meteor): how to set default route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've 4 views (templates):

- start
- showScannedData
- dashboard
- loading

I defined routing in **client_server/lib/routing.js**:

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});


Router.route('/', {
    name:'start',
    template:'start'
});

Router.route('/mobile', {
    name:'mobileStart',
    template:'showScannedData'
});

Router.route('/desktop', {
    name:'desktopStart',
    template:'dashboard'
});
```

In **client/app.js** I put:

```
Router.go('/start');
```

It works. However the template **showScannedData** is rendered twice, as if I set it as **templateLayout** too.
As for my application **I don't need a default layout** but single individuals view to be loaded either on start (template: start) or on a specific action performed by the user (templates: showScannedData / dashboard).

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Is the showScannedData template by any chance added to the <body> or to another template as well?

Comment: no and I don't usi <body> at all since I know it's added by Iron router

Comment: is there anotherp place you render showScannedData

Comment: figure out what was wrong. check out my answer. thank you for your hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @piscator and @Keith for giving me a key hint.

I figure out that, while I wasn't rendering the template twice, I put

```
{{>> showScannedData}}
```

in **project_name.html** file (i.e. the file rendered when routing is not used).

So I basically **removed the line above** from the file and used Iron's router to go to starter template by:

```
Router.go("/")
```

in **client/app.js**, which is defined in **client_server/lib/routing.js** as

```
Router.route('/', {
    name:'start',
    template:'start'
});
```

corresponding to

```
<template name="start">
    <input id="goToMobileBtn" type="button" value="Go to mobile view"/><br><br>
    <input id="goToDesktopBtn" type="button" value="Go to desktop view"/>
</template>
```

**Hint**: I found out that since "/" route is the **first** one defined in **routing.js**, the **Router.go** is optional.